# i moved magento1 store from one server to another server, it is displaying only half page except for homepage and admin

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, css, permissions

i moved magento1 store from one server to another server, it is displaying only half page except for homepage and admin, phtml files and cms pages are not loading.
[image]

Comment: There are generating error after some portion loading. can you right click and go to view source and checking the error.

Comment: Thank you i got the error, it works